# injective hull of a ring that is not integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-module

If $R$ is an integral domain, then the injective hull of $R$ ($E(R)$ in symbol) is $Q(R)$. But what is $E(R)$, where $R$ is not an integral domain? In particular what is $E(R)$, where $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$, $k$ a field?

In fact, the main question for me is as follows:

Let $E=E(R)$, $Q_1=(x^2,y)/(x^2,xy)$, $Q_2=(x^2,x+y)/(x^2,xy)$. Then i guess that 
$(0  :_E  Q_1)\neq (0  :_E Q_2)$. But i can not prove this. (perhaps it was wrong!). Can one help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know the injective hull of $k=R/(x,y)$ and $R/xR$ as $R$-modules? The injective hull of $R$ is the direct sum of these two.

Comment: @ – Mohan No, I don't know. Can you explain more, please? Of course, i want some elements in $E(R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy))$ such that do not belong to $R$. Can you help me about this?

Comment: It is much better to look at a book on commutative algebra or for example the paper of Hyman Bass: Ubiquity of Gorenstein rings. If you do not have suitable access to a book or paper, I can try to give you some hints.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But if possible for you, see the main question that i added and hint me about this. Is $(0  :_E Q_1)\neq (0  :_E  Q_2)$ or i am mistaken? thanks and excuse me. @ – Mohan

Comment: @user26857 No; In fact i consider two primary decomposition of $0_R$. i.e. $0_R=(x)/(x^2,xy)\cap Q_1$ and $0_R=(x)/(x^2,xy)\cap Q_2$ and i guess that $(0  :_E Q_1)\neq (0  :_E Q_2)$. But without knowing elements of  $E$, i can not prove this conjecture. Can you help me about this? thanks.

Comment: If $S \subset R$ is set of nonzerodivisors  in $R$, then $S^{-1}R$ is an essential extension of $R$.